# Giving a linestring width to create a polygon

Tags: algorithm, gis, geo, wkt

I have a WKT linestring and I want to use it to search for intersections in postgis but the linestring has some level of error and won't perfectly intersect the things stored in postgis so I want to convert it to a polygon and give it `n` meters thickness so that it will intersect with things next to it.

An example of what I want to do. Green being the polygon created from the line
[image]

The language of the solution doesn't matter too much. I can adapt the solution to work so I am just looking for some general algorithm which can create the polygon. The linestring contains geographical coords so I think working out how far away `n` meters is could be difficult.

I think the best way to go about this is drawing normals off the linestring and marking the point that's far enough away

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this can be done with postgis. http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html

[image]

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(
 ST_GeomFromText(
  'LINESTRING(50 50,150 150,150 50)'
 ), 10, 'endcap=round join=round');
```